# JSON C# UPS Address Verification - Array/List Errors

Tags: c#, arrays, json, rest

I'm getting the following error and can't figure out how to resolve it:

> {"Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g.
> {"name":"value"}) into type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[OAuthWinForms2024.Objects.Candidate]'
> because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
> correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
> (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
> .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
> type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
> object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
> to deserialize from a JSON object.\r\nPath
> 'XAVResponse.Candidate.AddressClassification', line 1, position 213."}

Class file:

```
    private async void btnValidateAddress_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);
        var services = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
        var _httpClientFactory = services.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
        var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

        var accesstoken = txtAccessToken.Text.ToString();


        Candidate candidate = new Candidate();
        Root addressVerification = new Root();
        AddressKeyFormat addressKeyFormat = new AddressKeyFormat();
        List<string> addressline = new List<string> { "1109 9th", "", "" };

        addressKeyFormat.AddressLine = addressline;
        addressKeyFormat.PoliticalDivision1 = "AZ";
        addressKeyFormat.PoliticalDivision2 = "Phoenix";
        addressKeyFormat.PostcodePrimaryLow = "85007";
        addressKeyFormat.PostcodeExtendedLow = "";
        addressKeyFormat.Urbanization = "";
        addressKeyFormat.CountryCode = "US";

        candidate.AddressKeyFormat = addressKeyFormat;

        string jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(candidate);

        var jsonStringV = @"{XAVRequest: " + jsonString + "}";
        JObject myjson = JObject.Parse(jsonStringV);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accesstoken);

        var postData = new StringContent(myjson.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var Requestoption = "3";
        var Version = "v1";
        var request = await client.PostAsync("https://onlinetools.ups.com/api/addressvalidation/" + Version + "/" + Requestoption + "?regionalrequestindicator=string&maximumcandidatelistsize=1", postData);
        var response = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

ERROR IS THROWN HERE ON THIS STATEMENT: 
        Root addressVerification2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(response);
    }
```

Properties:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace OAuthWinForms2024.Objects
{


    // Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
    public class AddressClassification
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class AddressKeyFormat
    {
        public string ConsigneeName { get; set; }
        public string AttentionName { get; set; }
        public List<string> AddressLine { get; set; }
        public string Region { get; set; }
        public string PoliticalDivision2 { get; set; }
        public string PoliticalDivision1 { get; set; }
        public string PostcodePrimaryLow { get; set; }
        public string PostcodeExtendedLow { get; set; }
        public string Urbanization { get; set; }
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class Alert
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class Candidate
    {
        public AddressClassification AddressClassification { get; set; }
        public AddressKeyFormat AddressKeyFormat { get; set; }
    }

    public class Response
    {
        public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
        public List<Alert> Alert { get; set; }
        public TransactionReference TransactionReference { get; set; }
    }

    public class ResponseStatus
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public XAVResponse XAVResponse { get; set; }
    }

    public class TransactionReference
    {
        public string CustomerContext { get; set; }
    }

    public class XAVResponse
    {
        public Response Response { get; set; }
        public string ValidAddressIndicator { get; set; }
        public string AmbiguousAddressIndicator { get; set; }
        public string NoCandidatesIndicator { get; set; }
        public AddressClassification AddressClassification { get; set; }
        public List<Candidate> Candidate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I thought I was using all Lists, but I'm a little lost.

Comment: It sounds like the JSON structure and the C# class structure are different.  Specifically on the `Candidate` property on the `XAVResponse` class.  You'll probably want to examine the JSON you're using to see its structure.

Comment: It may be requiring `XAVResponse.Candidate.AddressClassification` to be a list.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is running into object syntax "`{}`" where your model is expecting a `List<Candidate>`. Looking at your model, you probably just need to change the `Candidate` property to be a single `Candidate` instead of a list of them.

```
    public class XAVResponse
    {
        public Response Response { get; set; }
        public string ValidAddressIndicator { get; set; }
        public string AmbiguousAddressIndicator { get; set; }
        public string NoCandidatesIndicator { get; set; }
        public AddressClassification AddressClassification { get; set; }
        public Candidate Candidate { get; set; }
    }
```